# Handle Navigation Back Button

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin

I have two fragments, `A` and `B`. Fragment `A` launches `B`.

```
findNavController().navigate(R.id.action_A_to_B)
```

Now in Fragment `B` I have a button on the UI to return to Fragment `A`. How should I do this using the NavController? Should I just create an Action in my navigation? Or can I just do something that will return to the caller?

I ask because adding an Action means that `A -> B` and `B -> A` in the graph looks kinda weird.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to get the `NavController` and call `popBackStack()` to remove the fragment `B` from your stack again:

```
findNavController().popBackStack()
```